# Example of a convex function on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: optimization, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Hello to all the community, I am just getting into Riemannian Manifolds, applied to the case of optimization. Now I'm stuck looking for an example of a function that is convex within a Riemannian manifold $M$.

Although it is true to say that a function is convex on the manifold, do we say that its geodesics have to be totally included in the variety?

If so, I'd like to see some function that complies with it. It would help me a lot.

Comment: For instance, $f(x)=|x|^2$ is a convex function on $R^n$ equipped with the standard flat Riemannian  metric. More generally, if $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold, $p\in M$, then $d^2(p,x)$ is a convex function when restricted to a sufficiently small neighborhood of $p$. Are you looking for something more complicated?